How can I add current file size to the file name
I lost heaps of important data, plus failed backups etc. I did some recoveries but laptop drive had other plans, pushed data out of valid files + some recovery files had mismatched names or recovered files full of zeros (wiped data).
Because there’s been so many files & many have SHA56 hash names, accidentally recovered the same thing on occasion instead of what I need.
I’ve been running a command on files I’ve reviewed & don’t need to add “DELETE DONT RECOVER” to end of file name (or “EMPTY” if full of zeros) so I don’t recover it again.
I want to add the current file size in case the tool mismatches again as (unless it’s a photo) can’t confirm before physical recovery. Or will the tool just present the original file size & mismatch after the review?
Current command used.
for /R %a in ({asterisk}.*) do ren "%~a" "%~na DELETE DONT RECOVER%~xa"

I'm happy to run a separate command for file size, just needs to be accurate.

Keep in mind, a file can have 2 different sizes. Expected filesize, and size on disk. the expected filesize is written in the MBR in addition to where on the harddisk the file is stored, but the actual filesize is based on which data is actually present on the disk. If you use the expected filesize for a file that has 0 bytes on disk, it may create a file with garbage in it.

@LPChip sorry, thats not relevant. I’m doing it purely so once I’ve decided i dont beed the file and remove it, when i do recoveries again i can do a quick spot check and make sure that the files i marked as not needing to be recovered are not suddenly larger and posdibly holding data of items I actually need.

I want to add the current file size
Use %~z1 (Display the file size)
Example:
for /R %a in ({asterisk}.*) do ren "%~a" "%~na DELETE DONT RECOVER% - size %~za%~xa"
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Further Reading

An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com
Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com
Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com


thank you! thats perfect!

my command is suddenly only recursing in a single file and the command is no different from yesterday? any ideas

@echo off

2>nul cd /d "D:\Root\Dir" || goto :EoF 

for /f tokens^=1-4*^delims^=^  %%i in ('
     "%__AppDir__%where.exe" /t /r . "*.*"
    ')do ren "%%~m" "%%~nm [Strings] Size - %%~i%%~xm"



"my command is suddenly only recursing in a single file and the command is no different from yesterday? any ideas"
Try a recursive command to list the files in a For /F loop, and do the relevant output manipulations necessary to rename them


Some further reading:

CD /?

Where /?

For /?

For /F /?

Redirection:

| >nul 2>nul 2>&1 <nul < > ...


Where does GOTO :EOF return to?

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com


